# iOS Safari not unlocking Web AudioContext on swipe

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, web-audio-api

iOS doesn't allow Web Audio to be used without a user input to trigger it. To get around this, we have a `touchend` listener that does this:

```
       initAudio: function () {

            // create a blank buffer
            var buffer = this._atx.createBuffer(1, 1, 22050); // this._atx is the AudioContext
            var node = this._atx.createBufferSource();
            node.buffer = buffer;

            node.start(0); // or noteOn if the browser doesn't support this, removed that check/code for brevity
        }
```

This is working fine in most cases. We have an overlay over the game, which intercepts the first click, and calls the above function. At the end of the function, `this._atx.state` is `"running"` (it is `"suspended"` before the `node.start(0)` call).

However, if the callback is triggered by a quick swipe on the screen, rather than a tap, it goes through this code, and at the end of the function, the state is still `"suspended"`. It does exactly the same code both times, the only difference is the nature of the user input.

This is the code that adds the listeners:

```
        this._boundSoundTapped = this._onSoundTapped.bind(this);
        this._confirmPopup.addEventListener("touchend", this._boundSoundTapped);
        this._confirmPopup.addEventListener("click", this._boundSoundTapped);
```

And the `onSoundTapped` function:

```
    _onSoundTapped: function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        if(this._soundsPressed === false) {
            this._confirmPopup.removeEventListener("touchend", this._boundSoundTapped);
            this._confirmPopup.removeEventListener("click", this._boundSoundTapped);
            this._soundsPressed = true;
            this._player.initAudio();
        }
    },
```

I really can't see why the swipe rather than the click would have a different effect, they both trigger `touchend`, and the same code gets executed either way.